# How do I test a final classifier in test set?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

After tunning parameters for a classifier I build a model using the best ones. I decided to perform a `StratifiedKFold` as a validation. First I split my dataset in train and test so that I can check my model on a different test set. The thing is that since I applied a Kfold cross-validation the accuracies I get are from the virtual validation set. Now I get those performances I want to test the model in that test set we kept above but don't know how to proceed properly.
I know that an alternative could be to perform the kfold cross validation with the entire dataset (X,y)  but I decided to keep a test set beacuse I have to build more classifiers.
Here is my code for a classifier:

```
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 
kfold = StratifiedKFold(y_train,
    n_folds=10,
    random_state=42)
pipe_xgb = Pipeline([('xgb', XGBClassifier(learning_rate =0.01,
    n_estimators=5000,
    max_depth=4,
    min_child_weight=6,
    gamma=0,
    subsample=0.8,
    colsample_bytree=0.8,
    objective= 'binary:logistic',
    nthread=4,
    scale_pos_weight=2.7, #ratio of positive and negative classes
    seed=42))])
pipe_xgb.fit(X_train, y_train)
scores = []
for k, (train, val) in enumerate(kfold):
    pipe_xgb.fit(X_train[train], y_train[train])#fit on train 
    score = pipe_xgb.score(X_train[val], y_train[val])#test on val
    scores.append(score)
    print('Fold: %s, Class dist.: %s, Acc: %.3f' % (k+1,
            np.bincount(y_train[train]), score))
print('CV accuracy: %.3f +/- %.3f' % (np.mean(scores), np.std(scores)))
```

I was thinking in making predictions with the test set an call for some parameters using the model I train above but I am not sure if that is the proper way of testing on test_set:
This is what I tried on the test set:

```
y_pred = pipe_xgb.predict(X_test)
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
target_names = ['class 0', 'class 1']
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
from sklearn.metrics import matthews_corrcoef
print('Matthew coefficient')
print()
print(matthews_corrcoef(y_test, pipe_xgb.predict(X_test)))
print('Confusion matrix')
print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test,pipe_xgb.predict(X_test)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when people set aside a validation set, and then go for a cross validation, it's because they want to find the best parameters on the training set. `sklearn` gives you two nice functions for doing so, which are under the [`GridSearch`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html). When you use `GridSearchCV`, you can set the `refit` to `True`, which would result in training the model with the best parameters on the whole training data, which then you can use on your set aside validation set.

Also, you don't have to use a `Pipeline` if there's only one item in it.

A `GridSearchCV` example taken from [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV):

```
>>> from sklearn import svm, datasets
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
>>> iris = datasets.load_iris()
>>> parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':[1, 10]}
>>> svc = svm.SVC()
>>> clf = GridSearchCV(svc, parameters)
>>> clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
...                             
GridSearchCV(cv=None, error_score=...,
       estimator=SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=..., class_weight=..., coef0=...,
                     decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=..., gamma=...,
                     kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False,
                     random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=...,
                     verbose=False),
       fit_params=None, iid=..., n_jobs=1,
       param_grid=..., pre_dispatch=..., refit=..., return_train_score=...,
       scoring=..., verbose=...)
>>> sorted(clf.cv_results_.keys())
...                             
['mean_fit_time', 'mean_score_time', 'mean_test_score',...
 'mean_train_score', 'param_C', 'param_kernel', 'params',...
 'rank_test_score', 'split0_test_score',...
 'split0_train_score', 'split1_test_score', 'split1_train_score',...
 'split2_test_score', 'split2_train_score',...
 'std_fit_time', 'std_score_time', 'std_test_score', 'std_train_score'...]
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem is once you have your model trained (after the whole tunning process). I mean how we apply the test set to check how the model performs in brand new data.

Comment: what do you mean by "apply the test set to check how the model performs in brand new data"? You check the performance of the model on the test set, which gives you an expected value for the accuracy, and then when given brand new data, for which you usually don't have the desired output, you just do `model.predict(input)` to get the output values.

Comment: What I mean is once I have my model trained How exactly I test my model on test set after a cross-validation?.This means what I did above makes any sense? `y_pred = pipe_xgb.predict(X_test)` ? Is this the proper way of testing my model on test set after a cross-validation procedure?